# Restful App with Spring MVC - Ambiguous handler methods error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a Restful webapp using Spring MVC 4.
But I'm got this error "Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP".
In my controller I have this endpoints:

GET /people/
GET /people/{id}
POST /people/
DELETE /peope/{id}
PUT /people/{id}

I think this error occurs because I have something wrong in my configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myapp.rest.controller" })
public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/site/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/site/**");
    }
}
```

And this

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");

    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.myapp.config");
        return context;
    }

}
```

Thank you all

Comment: Can you add your people controller(s)?

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with your `@RequestMapping` definitions. Please show them.

Comment: Seems like duplicate request mapping parameters.